# Elasticsearch sort order by float looks wrong

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a field in each doc that contains a Float, which is meant as a fallback way to order the docs. Since it is a floating point number it can be negative. When I ask Elasticsearch to `"order": "desc"` I get the largest negative value first then the less negative. This is wrong, it is as if the sign is ignored, which is not at all what I wanted.

```
"popRank": {
    "unmapped_type": "float",
    "order": "desc"
}
```

The part of the doc looks like this:

```
"popRank": -310,
```

If the query uses `desc` I get -310 first, -157 next. Not completely sure what happens when there are positive numbers because there aren't any in this small test dataset.

Comment: seems like a lexicographical  sort check the mapping is `popRank` of type `float` or `string` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to make sure your `popRank` field is mapped as `float` and not `string`

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index/_mapping/your_type?fields=popRank
```

should return you this:

```
{
  "your_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "your_type" : {
        "properties" : {
          "popRank" : {
            "type" : "float"         <---- "float" MUST appear here and NOT "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We can test float sorting very simply like this. First, let's create a test index:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "popRank": {
          "type": "float"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then we add some documents with `popRank` in the whole spectrum.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/test/_bulk -d '
{"index": {"_id": 1}}
{"popRank": 123}
{"index": {"_id": 2}}
{"popRank": -157}
{"index": {"_id": 3}}
{"popRank": 1234}
{"index": {"_id": 4}}
{"popRank": 0}
{"index": {"_id": 5}}
{"popRank": -310}
{"index": {"_id": 6}}
{"popRank": 332}
{"index": {"_id": 7}}
{"popRank": -10}
'
```

Finally, we can shake this out with

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/test/_search -d '{
    "sort": {
        "popRank": {
            "unmapped_type": "float",
            "order": "desc"
        }
    },
    "query": {"match_all": {}}
}'
```

And in the results, I see all the documents properly sorted by `popRank`, i.e. `1234, 332, 123, 0, -10, -157, -310`

So make sure that your `popRank` field wasn't indexed as a `string` in the first place, because if this was the case, the sample documents above would have been sorted like this: `332, -310, -157, 1234, 123, -10, 0`, which is what seems to be happening in your case.

Comment: You were right that popRank was mapped as a string. It is written to the index with a Map[String, Any] using Spark. One part of the Map was  "popRank" -> n, where n was a Float. Writing the entire index to ES with `rdd[Map[String, Any]].saveToEs(esIndexURI, Map("es.mapping.id" -> "id")` The part "es.mapping.id" -> "id" tells ES to use the "id" association in the rdd's `MAP`` as the doc-id. Is there some way to map the popRank to a float, I thought it would determine this from reflection but maybe not.

Comment: I really appreciate that you have hit on the problem exactly. I'd mark this as the answer but I don't see the solution above. How, using `rdd.saveAsEs(index, mappings)` can I write popRank mapped to a Float?

Comment: I think the final bit is to create the field to type mapping when the index is created. then all is well, thanks

Comment: Yes, glad you figured it out. The best is to create the mapping at index creation time and then you'll always be fine.